# How to get the ID of the spinner?

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, xamarin

I want to get the: "ID" of the selected item from a spinner.

Here is my code:

```
var sterren1Lems = new String[]
         {
                "1 out of 5 stars", "2 out of 5 stars", "3 out of 5 stars", "4 out of 5 stars", "5 out of 5 stars"
         };

            sterren2Lems = FindViewById<Spinner>(Resource.Id.sterrenLems);
            sterren2Lems.Adapter = new ArrayAdapter<string>(this, Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleSpinnerDropDownItem, sterren1Lems);

            TextView test = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.test);

            sterren2Lems.ItemSelected += delegate
            {
                test.Text = sterren1Lems[Convert.ToInt32(sterren2Lems.SelectedItemId)];
            };
```

Please help me!

Comment: One hint is first get the text and `substring` it.

Comment: Why should I use substring, when I only want the: id/value of the selected text?

Comment: Aren't you willing to get `1` from `"1 out of 5 stars"` ?

Comment: That's what I want and when I got: "3 out of 5 stars" I want the id: 3

Comment: Substring is about the lenght of the text, right?

Comment: Are you able to get `"1 out of 5 stars"` from `spinner` then ?

Comment: yeah, I can select the arrays.

Comment: Then do `string id = new String(yourSelectedString.TakeWhile(Char.IsDigit).ToArray());`

Comment: "yourSelectedString", what do I need to type there?

Comment: The string variable where `"1 out of 5 stars"` is stored.

Comment: You mean: "sterren1Lems"?

Comment: No the selected one single string, That is an array so You cant do it with array. You just told you are able to get that single selected string's value from spinner, isn't it ?

Comment: I only get text in the spinner, but the id not.

Comment: yah that's the point and that text is `yourSelectedString`. Did you get ?

Comment: But when I click on array[3], I want id: 4

Comment: You will surely get that. Just try above hint once !!

Comment: I tried this: sterren2Lems.ItemSelected += delegate
            {
                string id = new String("2 out of 5 stars".TakeWhile(Char.IsDigit).ToArray());

                test.Text = id.ToString();
            };

Comment: But I get the value: 5 always, because there 5 arrays

Comment: Ohh, then use regex, so try `String id = Regex.Match("2 out of 5 stars", @"^\d+").ToString();`

Comment: I get a red line below: "Regex".

Comment: Are you sure you imported `System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex` ?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't do that, because they gave a error.

Comment: No error, now I'm going to test it

Comment: I still get the value: "5".

Comment: If you are still getting 5 with my answer, then follow @Andres Castro. He seems familiar with xamarin more than me...

Comment: I'm going to test it all again, because I didn't rebuild, so maybe it was right.

Comment: I tried: string id = new String("2 out of 5 stars".TakeWhile(Char.IsDigit).ToArray()) and I got the value 2 so that's good!

Comment: Haha... The below one is also good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either of approach in your case didn't work, I got to know by discussion that you are able to get a single `string` from array. So that just use simple loop to get the `id`.

```
sting yourString ="2 out of 5 stars";
string id = "";

for (int i = 0; i < yourString.Length; i++)
{
    if (Char.IsDigit(yourString[i]))
        result += str[i];
    else
        break;
}
```

OR

```
string id = new String(yourString.TakeWhile(Char.IsDigit).ToArray());
```

Comment: But now I need to get the value of the selected one and not from 1 string

Comment: As I know Andres already told you about getting the selected text from spinner. And you also told that you were able to get that.

Comment: But it didn't work first and now I need his code again with +1, but I forgot it

Comment: @SanderLemmen Do `String yourString= sterren2Lems.getSelectedItem().toString();`

Comment: I cannot use getSelectedItem(). Do you know why?

Comment: Thanks! I fixed it with this code: string id = new String(sterren1Lems[e.Position].TakeWhile(Char.IsDigit).ToArray());
            test.Text = id.ToString();                                                              You and Andres are heroes!

Comment: @SanderLemmen What happened ? is there any issue raised ? Can you tell me the reason of unaccepting the answer ?

Comment: When I select a text value, I don't get the number value

Comment: @SanderLemmen May be, But You are telling this as wrong after more than 1 month. You can suggest the edit, If you've corrected that.

Comment: I was busy with the website

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't have to pull any value inside of the string. You know the value just by the position of the item selected.

```
sterren2Lems.ItemSelected += Sterren2Lems_ItemSelected;

void Sterren2Lems_ItemSelected (object sender, AdapterView.ItemSelectedEventArgs e)
{
     test.Text = sterren1Lems[e.Position];
}
```

Comment: I always get the value: "5", because there are 5 arrays.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. With the code above you get the number 5 position even if you select the first item?

Comment: Updated my code to remove the +1 it was adding. If you don't see something different in your e.Position every time you select a different row then something else is wrong.

Comment: I'm going to close the emulator and start it again

Comment: You are Rebuilding correct after your changes right? Not just changing code and testing it in your emulator? Right click on your project and click 'Build'.

Comment: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Comment: On this line:   sterren2Lems = FindViewById<Spinner>(Resource.Id.sterrenLems);
            sterren2Lems.ItemSelected += Sterren2Lems_ItemSelected;

Comment: That means your spinner isn't in your view anymore. It can't find a spinner with the id sterrenLems.

Comment: Thanks! I fixed it with this code: string id = new String(sterren1Lems[e.Position].TakeWhile(Char.IsDigit).ToArray());
            test.Text = id.ToString();                                                              You and Shree are heroes!